# cant run start-all.sh hadoop ubuntu

Tags: hadoop, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I took all the necessary steps for hadoop installation on ubuntu 14.04.
But when i try to run "start-all.sh" after "hadoop namenode" -format' it shows error(mainly) :

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
pdsh@k-Inspiron-5537: localhost: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
Starting datanodes
pdsh@k-Inspiron-5537: localhost: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
Starting secondary namenodes [k-Inspiron-5537]
pdsh@k-Inspiron-5537: k-Inspiron-5537: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
Starting nodemanagers
pdsh@k-Inspiron-5537: localhost: rcmd: socket: Permission denied
```

how to give pdsh package permission?
Can anybody help me please?

Comment: try echo "ssh" > /etc/pdsh/rcmd_default

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the complete path for the start-all.sh.

Try to run :

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/start-all.sh
```

Since start-all.sh and stop-all.sh located in sbin directory while hadoop binary file is located in bin directory.

Also updated your .bashrc for:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin
```

so that you can directly access start-all.sh

Answer (score 0):

What you could have missed while installing is "passwordless ssh" or may be not configured in proper way.

What you need to do is :

1) install **ssh** using "**sudo apt-get install ssh**".

2) Generate SSH key using **ssh-keygen -t rsa -P '' -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa**.

3) And now configure password less ssh using public rsa key to a file **authorized_keys**  using **cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub>>~/.ssh/authorized_keys**

4) And then give the permission to this new file using **chmod 0600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys**

5) Now try to ssh using **ssh localhost**. it will ask for "Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?" then type yes.

after the first step i you see message as **Permanently added 'localhost' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts**, then you have configured PasswordLess ssh successfully.

Now try to format namenode, and then run command **start-all.sh**. follow [this](http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php) for more.

**Edited:**

try below command for pdsh error : “rcmd: socket: Permission denied”

```
echo "ssh" > /etc/pdsh/rcmd_default
```

Comment: Problem remains the same

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered the same thing, I did so I found that my pdsh default rcmd is rsh, not ssh, rsh and ssh remote login authentication is not the same, when installing hadoop I configured ssh localhost password-free login, but rsh is not possible.

so，try：

1.check your pdsh default rcmd rsh

pdsh -q -w localhost
See what your pdsh default rcmd is.

2.Modify pdsh's default rcmd to ssh

export PDSH_RCMD_TYPE=ssh
you can be added to ~/.bashrc, and source ~/.bashrc

3.sbin / start-dfs.sh